# laravel 9 has defferent location then i set, and every file i put become .tmp

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-9, file-storage

i dont understand why, i do it in laravel 8 and it work but not in laravel 9

Store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $ValidatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:menus',
        'categories_id' => 'required',
        'deskripsi' => 'required',
        'is_order' => 'required',
        'most' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'image' => 'image|file|max:1024'
    ]);

    if($request->file('image')){
        $validatedData['image'] = $request->image->store('menus');
    }

    $ValidatedData['users_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
    $ValidatedData['excerpt'] = Str::limit(strip_tags($request->deskripsi), 100);
    Menus::create($ValidatedData);
    return Redirect('/dashboard/menus')->with('success', 'Tugas Baru Telah Ditambahkan!');
}
```

Form

```
<div class="mb-3">
        <label for="image" class="form-label">Size Max. 1mb</label>
        <input class="form-control @error('image') is-invalid @enderror" type="file" 
        name="image" id="image">
        @error('image')
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          {{ $message }}
        </div>
        @enderror
      </div>
```

.env

```
FILESYSTEM_DISK=public
```

After Create the storage location is change

[image]

Comment: its a typo ... `$validatedData != $ValidatedData`

Comment: Dayum I embarrassed, thanks man 